# I keep getting this error when trying to use a route in a widget. "The element type 'Route<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'."

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I want to use the following dynamic route here:

```
Route fadeTransitionHomeScreen() {
      return PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const HomeScreen(),
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2450),
        transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c),
      );
    }
```

And use it in a widget here:

```
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    fadeTransitionHomeScreen(),  // where error is
    DoctorAppointmentScreen(),
    PrescriptionScreen(),
    ChatMenu(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];
```

My main goal is to add a transition effect when travelling to a page. The hard part is that i want this transition animation on a navbar. How can i go about doing this?
I keep getting the error: "The element type 'Route' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'."

Get widget option:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
```

Comment: fadeTransitionHomeScreen is a Route variable, but the list you add only accepts Widgets.

Comment: fadeTransitionHomeScreen can only be used as

Navigator.of(context).push(fadeTransitionHomeScreen());

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_bar_page_transition